# xray-rails not working with rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, xray-rails

I installed [xray-rails](https://github.com/brentd/xray-rails) on a Rails 5.1 app but pressing the keyboard shortcut does nothing. I already cleared cached assets `rails tmp:clear`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 5.1 dropped jQuery as a dependency. Add it to the Gemfile explicitly:

```
group :development do
  gem 'xray-rails'
  gem 'jquery-rails' # add it outside the group if you need it globally
end
```

Then import it in application.js:

```
//= require jquery
```

And you can Cmd + Shift + X again.